# Median of pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, r, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df`:

```
name   count    
aaaa   2000    
bbbb   1900    
cccc    900    
dddd    500    
eeee    100
```

I would like to look at the rows that are within a factor of 10 from the median of the `count` column.

I tried `df['count'].median()` and got the median. But don't know how to proceed further. Can you suggest how I could use pandas/numpy for this.

Expected Output :

```
name count distance from median

aaaa  2000   *****
```

I can use any measure as the distance from median (absolute deviation from median, quantiles etc.).

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is now shown in original post

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're looking for how to calculate the [Median Absolute Deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) -

```
In [1]: df['dist'] = abs(df['count'] - df['count'].median())

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   name  count  dist
0  aaaa   2000  1100
1  bbbb   1900  1000
2  cccc    900     0
3  dddd    500   400
4  eeee    100   800

In [3]: df['dist'].median()
Out[3]: 800.0
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see the median, you can use df.describe(). The 50% value is the median.

Comment: can you also mention what does the 25% and 75% REALLY mean?

Comment: @Prometheus that would be the first and third quartile of the list respectively.

Answer (score 1):

[Median absolute deviation,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation)

[image]

for a column could also be calculated using [`statsmodels.robust.scale.mad`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.robust.scale.mad.html#statsmodels-robust-scale-mad), which can also be passed a normalization constant `c` which in this case is just 1.

```
>>> from statsmodels.robust.scale import mad
>>> mad(df['count'], c=1)
800.0
```